Discrete simulation of a Levy flight
I am trying to construct a discrete simulation of Levy flight in 1D and am wondering what is the best way to do so.
For example, for pure diffusive random walk, one may assign probability of $1/2$ to a step to right and a step to left. So if a uniform random number generator yields less than half, the particle moves a step to the left, otherwise it moves to the right.
The probability distribution of Levy flight (as I understand) can be written as follows:
\begin{equation}
Pr\big(\vec{s}\big) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \hspace{2mm} |\vec{s}|<s_0 \\
C{|\vec{s}|}^{-\alpha} & \hspace{2mm} |\vec{s}|>s_0 \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here $\vec{s}$ is the jump vector. C appears because of normalization. I have a couple of questions on how to simulate this phenomenon (using a computer program) on a discrete 1D lattice consisting of N>>1 sites:

Is the probability distribution as written correct for a Levy flight?
What is $s_0$ and how to choose $s_0$?
What is a valid way to pick step lengths based on the probability distribution given above in a computer simulation (as we can do for pure random walk)?


Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52869/207316 But I'm not sure how that applies to a 1-D walk. How do you choose the direction? Do you just choose it randomly (eg from a uniform distribution)?

Thanks for the comment. The direction can be controlled by another random variable. They had a random variable theta in the example you cited.
